# The image I add in the card in Flutter does not cover the entire card

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Image.network(
                    networkImage,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

I made the fit property 'cover' under the image. But the image is not distributed over the entire card.

Comment: why need `Column`?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to make your `Image` inside a `Column` widget, then you can wrap it with `Expanded` widget like this:

```
Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Column(
           // MainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Image.network(
                  "https://via.placeholder.com/200x50",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

if you don't actually need to set it inside a `Column`, then you can just use it like this:

```
Center(
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Image.network(
            "https://via.placeholder.com/200x50",
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```